# Class in Stack - this.props undefined - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a screen in my stack by using onPress on a Google Map Marker.

When I click the marker I receive:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this11.props.navigation').

I believe it's telling me this.props does not exist from the marker, but why? What do I need to pass to it and how?

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    FlatList,
    Button,
    Component
} from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import {
    createStackNavigator,
    createBottomTabNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import { oauth, net } from "react-native-force";
import { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { Callout } from "react-native-maps";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    item: {
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        height: 44
    },
    map: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0
    }
});

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>Home!</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Go to Settings"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings")}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Go to Details"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details")}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class LocationDetailScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>Home!</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Go to Settings"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings")}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Go to Details"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details")}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var that = this;
        oauth.getAuthCredentials(
            () => that.fetchData(), // already logged in
            () => {
                oauth.authenticate(
                    () => that.fetchData(),
                    error => console.log("Failed to authenticate:" + error)
                );
            }
        );
    }

    fetchData() {
        var that = this;
        net.query(
            "SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone FROM User LIMIT 10",
            response => that.setState({ data: response.records })
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>Settings!</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Go to Home"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Go to Details"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details")}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class UserListScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Map"
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            error: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var that = this;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                console.log("wokeeey");
                console.log(position);
                this.setState({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                    error: console.log("this is broken")
                });
            },
            error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
            { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        );

        oauth.getAuthCredentials(
            () => that.fetchData(), // already logged in
            () => {
                oauth.authenticate(
                    () => that.fetchData(),
                    error => console.log("Failed to authenticate:" + error)
                );
            }
        );
    }

    fetchData() {
        var that = this;
        net.query(
            "SELECT Id, Name, Type__c, Lat_Long__Latitude__s, Lat_Long__Longitude__s FROM Location__c LIMIT 10",
            response => that.setState({ data: response.records })
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text> {this.state.latitude} </Text>
                <Text> {this.state.longitude} </Text>
                <Text> {this.state.error} </Text>

                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <Text style={styles.item}>
                            {item.Name} - {item.Type__c}
                        </Text>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => "key_" + index}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Some Map"
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var that = this;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                console.log("wokeeey");
                console.log(position);
                this.setState({
                    region: {
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0462,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0261
                    }
                });
            },
            error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
            { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        );

        oauth.getAuthCredentials(
            () => that.fetchData(), // already logged in
            () => {
                oauth.authenticate(
                    () => that.fetchData(),
                    error => console.log("Failed to authenticate:" + error)
                );
            }
        );
    }

    fetchData() {
        var that = this;
        net.query(
            "SELECT Id, Name, Type__c, Lat_Long__Latitude__s, Lat_Long__Longitude__s FROM Location__c LIMIT 10",
            response => that.setState({ data: response.records })
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MapView style={styles.map} region={this.state.region}>
                {this.state.data.map(function (marker) {
                    return (
                        <Marker
                            onPress={() =>
                                this.props.navigation.navigate(
                                    "LocationDetailScreen"
                                )
                            }
                            coordinate={{
                                latitude: marker.Lat_Long__Latitude__s,
                                longitude: marker.Lat_Long__Longitude__s
                            }}
                            title={marker.Name}
                            description="hello"
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </MapView>
        );
    }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    LocationDetails: { screen: LocationDetailScreen }
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen }
});

const DetailsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
    LocationDetails: { screen: LocationDetailScreen }
});

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: HomeStack },
        Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
        Details: { screen: DetailsStack }
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;
                if (routeName === "Home") {
                    iconName = `rocket${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
                } else if (routeName === "Settings") {
                    iconName = `rocket${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
                }

                // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
                // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
                return <Icon name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            }
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: "tomato",
            inactiveTintColor: "gray"
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: It's important to highlight the navigation prop is not passed in to all components; only screen components receive this prop automatically! React Navigation doesn't do anything magic here. More here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Comment: @AravindS, thanks. I have read through the documentation here, do you know what I must do to be able to navigate to a screen from onpress of the marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your case is not using an arrow function in your data map function, so you're losing the scope of "this"

Can you try it like so?

```
{
this.state.data.map(marker => {
    return (
        <Marker
            onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate("LocationDetailScreen")
            }
            coordinate={{
                latitude: marker.Lat_Long__Latitude__s,
                longitude: marker.Lat_Long__Longitude__s
            }}
            title={marker.Name}
            description="hello"
        />
    );
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. When I click the marker, no error or screen is returned.

Comment: You're trying to navigate to a wrong Screen name. It should be navigate("LocationDetails") not LocationDetailScreen

Comment: Bingo. Thanks for putting up with this.